# Deviding Text box value by number c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying the following code but i get zero result!!

```
textBox13.Text = (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) / 536).ToString ();
```

Comment: Maybe because you get an exception. What is the content of `textbox1.Text`? You should really use better names for your controls. Otherwise it decreases readability and is  a source of errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you do integer division.

Try

```
textBox13.Text = (double.Parse(textbox1.Text) / 536).ToString();
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are expecting result set in `0.0...` a double /float number. You may divide by 536.0 or 536d

```
textBox13.Text = (int.Parse(textbox1.Text) / 536d).ToString ();//or 536.0
```

Currently your calculation is being done in integer type. You may cast either of the two oprands to type double/float.

Answer (score 1):

already answerd bu i'd suggest using `TryParse`

```
double d = 0;
if(double.TryParse(textbox1.Text,out d))
{
    textBox13.Text = (d/536.0).ToString();
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("There is no valid number in the textbox");
}
```